# testing for number or NOT integer in if/while/for

Tags: python

I am trying to get a user to input a number into a calculator program. The goal right now is to keep giving the user an error message and asking to reenter a number until they enter a real number.

here is some code that I've done:

```
number_1 = input("Enter your first number here! ")
while number_1 == int():
    print("Well done for entering a number!")
```

Comment: `int()` returns `0`, so you are checking if `number_1 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `isdigit()`

```
number_1 = input("Enter your first number here! ")
if str(number_1).isdigit():
    print("Well done for entering a number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `try: except:`?

```
def my_input(number_1):
    while 1:
        try:
            int(number_1)
            return number_1
        except:
            print("It is not an integer.")
            number_1 = input("Give an integer: ")

int1 = input("Enter your first number here! ")
my_input(int1)
print("Well done for entering a number!")
```

You may have to change `int(number_1)` to `float(number_1)` (and input text(s)) depending on your implementation.